# Firebase Firestore Cloud Function Never Execute

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I made Firestore Could Function Where I have Database Like this

```
'posts/{postId}/comments/{commentId}'
```

and Function I made To Increase Field In PostId when New Comment Added

the Funtion has Deploy But it`s Never Execute when adding New Comment

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.comment= functions.firestore
    .document('posts/{postId}/comments/{commentId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {

   const commentId = event.params.commentId; 
    const postId = event.params.postId;
 const docRef = admin.firestore().collection('posts').doc(postId);
 return docRef.update({numberOfComments:200});

    });
```

I Added Many Comment Even Executions is 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change this:

```
const commentId = event.params.commentId; 
const postId = event.params.postId;
```

into this:

```
const commentId = context.params.commentId; 
const postId = context.params.postId;
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Answer (score 0):

**Before Firebase SDK (<= v0.9.1)** version `event.params.id` was worked. but **Now (v1.0.0)** android provide documentation to use `context.params.id`.

Use `context` insted of `event`, your problem will be solve.

```
const commentId = event.params.commentId; 
const postId = event.params.postId;
```

Thanks.